# Supporting different voltage power bricks

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, ldo

I'm designing a simple PCB that will control some sensors/actuators with a microcontroller.

The microcontroller requires 3.3V and I'm planning to support different types of sensors/actuators that can require either 5V or 12V supplies, but all have 5V logic level.

3.3V: Easy, a step-down converter that accepts anywhere from 5V to 12V.

5V for the logic shifter: I could do the same as with 3.3V, but what if the power supply itself is 5v?

I've opened up a cheap LED strip controller I had laying around, one that supports any power brick from 5V to 24V. That controller has a buck converter for 3.3V and what seems to be an LDO (I can't read the part number,) bringing the 3.3V up to 5V for the logic shifter.

I could do the same, but that seems like a waste of energy so I was wondering if there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: An LDO can't bring 3v3 back up to 5. Could a buck-boost work for your case?

Comment: Right, so what I thought to be an LDO, must be another buck converter. Interesting

Comment: A buck converter also cannot bring a voltage *up*. A boost converter may, a charge pump may, but a buck converter by design bucks (lowers) a voltage.

Answer (score 1):

> *5v for the logic shifter: I could do the same as with 3.3v, but what
> if the power supply itself is 5v? I was wondering if there is a better way to go about this.*

I'd consider using a buck-boost converter. An example: -

[image]

If you need more than 1.5 amps, there are others to choose from. Other products made by TI will also do the job. The point I'm making is this: use a buck-boost regulator. ADI also provide this device for a 1 amp output: -

[image]